# Prevent Amibroker from entering the same day as its exit in the same symbol

Tags: amibroker

I am attempting to create a share/stock portfolio based system that will enter at the open and possibly exit on the same day at close if the conditions are met. I have this basicaly working. The thing i cant get going is that I would like my stock system to only ever have 1 open postion in a company at any time.

It seems that if there is both an exit and an entry on the same day, amibroker backtesting is allowing the same company to be purchased on the open, if that same company has a sell order on that same day. Here is an example of this:

[image]

Notice at point 1 - we would be entering at the open on the 17th
At point 2, we get a sell signal that day, so we should exit at Close on the 24th.
However at point 3 - we have an entry for the same company on the same day.

To be clear - I would like to allow multiple entries on the same day - this is working. The only thing i would like to figure out is to prevent the backtester from entering the SAME company on the SAME day it exits, as due to the system rules, we would have one day of having 2 positions in the 1 company.

Here is the sample code to replicate this:

```
SetOption("AllowSameBarExit", True );  
SetOption("SettlementDelay", 1 );

Buy = C > MA(C,10);
Sell = C < MA(C,10) OR C > O;

// trade on todays open
SetTradeDelays( 0, 0, 0, 0 );
BuyPrice = Open; 
SellPrice = Close;

SetPositionSize( 20, spsPercentOfEquity );
```

I have read and re-read the page on portfolio timing: [here](http://www.amibroker.com/guide/h_portfolio.html) but I still cant figure out how to prevent the entries for the same company on the same day as an exit.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**UPDATE** 
It appears that using the OR C > O in the SELL condition is effecting this. If I remove the OR C > O part, I get the correct behaviour. It is entering on the NEXT day. Now Im wondering how to use that exit without reverting back to same bar same company entry and exit...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Tomasz from Amibroker for posting the below solution:

```
SetOption("AllowSameBarExit", True );

BuyPrice = Open;
SellPrice = Close;

Buy = Ref( Close > MA( Close, 10 ), -1 );
Sell =  Close > Open OR Close < MA( Close,10);

// removing buys you don't want
intrade = False;
for( i = 0; i < BarCount; i++ )
{
    if( NOT intrade )
    {
        if( Buy[ i ] ) 
        {
            intrade = True;

            // same bar sell
            if( Sell[ i ] ) intrade = False;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if( Sell[ i ] ) 
        {
            intrade = False;
            Buy[ i ] = False; // remove buy if exited this bar
        }
    }
}
```

You can find : [a detailed discussion here](https://forum.amibroker.com/t/using-or-in-a-sell-condition-allows-mutliple-entries-on-same-symbol/6888)